# How to handle user/voting "something is off" feeling

Tags: discussion

After an [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7867299/438992) was unaccepted (fine in itself) I was poking around the two users (asker and newly-accepted answer, which duplicates my answer but with less info):

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/815693/user815693
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209087/kiril

I then noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780209/diffucilty-with-biginteger/10780452#10780452) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179105/438992) and find the timing/users a bit odd.

What's the normal procedure (if any)–flag with a custom message?

Just seems too much to be coincidental.

Comment: @Oded That it's the same two users, that a few questions were answered in the last two hours and accepted, displacing older, better answers, and the retro-accepts.

Comment: Fair enough. The only thing is, these are only 2 questions, and the asker has a bunch of others. 2 does not make a pattern yet, though it does seem odd...

Comment: @Oded It's actually three, and I understand it's not necessarily a "pattern".

Comment: Yes, leave a flag and we'll look at it. Unfortunately there isn't much else you can do at this point.

Comment: Oh and I deleted the answer because, as you said, it's a new answer which echoes what you said almost a year ago. We don't want that sort of thing around at all, whether there's anything more sinister going on.

Comment: It definitely seems odd that the asker would unaccept Dave's more detailed answer in exchange for the new one which very poorly copies Dave's answer. It's probably a good idea to keep an eye on those two as they are definitely up to something, IMHO.